# Rails - Where should I write the business logic?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

I have a model that stores some codes generated automatically by the app everytime a new user is created. Where should I write the logic of this "codes generator"? Controller or Model? If the answer is "Model", how do I do this? Thanks for your help!

Comment: If it's only used when creating a model, I think it makes the most sense to put it in the model's file. It would have to be a class method, rather than an instance method, because you need to call it before the instance is saved.

Comment: Ok, thanks Jason, I'll try it out in the Model.

Answer (score -1):

I would suggest creating an `app/services` folder and putting your `CodeGenerator` class/module in there.

This will result in something like:

```
# app/services/code_generator.rb
module CodeGenerator
  def self.generate(model)
    # logic to generate your code
  end
end
```

This way you keep the logic also separated from your models which could now be re-used for different models if needed. Also doing it like this will make your models only responsible for the ORM part and not additional logic like generating codes.

Comment: Thanks Bryan, not sure how it works, but I'll try it out as well.

Comment: Bryan could you explain how the controller would be after this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: @CamiloOrdonez you should call the 'service class' in your controller where you need it. Keep in mind that the above code snippet is just an example. I don't know which code you're trying to generate and perhaps it's not even necessary to pass in the model. 

How far did you come? Could you post a code snippet of your own, so we can help you out?